# Will copper wire with a non-tarnishing coating be insulated?

Tags: wire, insulation

I need to make a coil to test voltage created by flux for a project, but bought the wrong grade of wire. Will the non-tarnishing coating act as a good enough insulator for voltages in the millivolts?

TIA

Comment: Depends on the non-tarnishing coating. Gold, for example, is non-tarnishing but not an insulator. If it's the clear (or coloured) varnish commonly used on wire in transformers, it's good for a few volts. (Mains voltages usually require paper or mylar tape between layers of winding)

Comment: as long as you verify the insulation with a test ( no nicks.)  Polyester, Polyurethane are most common coatings

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's a lacquer coating if it's a crafts type wire so it would suffice for a very low voltage.

You can take a couple pieces and twist them roughly together and see if you can measure any continuity between the two. You'll need to remove the coating at the ends to make a reliable connection- soldering heat may well do the trick if it's a polyester lacquer. Be more gentle when you wind the actual coil, obviously.

[One manufacturer](https://contenti.com/beadsmith-tarnish-resistant-craft-wire) states that:

> The tarnish resistant feature results from an oven-baked clear coat finish